# Why do I see message "the world fades" on The Dusty Path?

Tags: a-dark-room

I am wandering around in the open map of The Dusty Path. I have HP and Water remaining but the world just fades to white and returns me to main screen. I see this message

> the world fades

How can I continue questing?

I lose my spear and my torches and my meat.

This is frustrating.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably ran out of cured meat.

If you notice, when you move on the map, you actually consume meat every few steps. If you run out of steps, starvation will "set in". Then, the world will fade as you die from starvation. If you have a trading post, eventually you can buy a wagon which lets you carry more on adventures.

Answer (score -3):

It is when you overstay or when the game hates you. I had 26 water and 40 cured meat when I died of starvation so it's not the meat or water. I did go around the entire map and died of starvation on my way back to the village to save. This happens a lot.

Comment: There is no way that this can be true. "the world fades" is either if you run out of water, run out of healthpoints or run out of food.